# Find minimum value of $P = \frac{y + z}{x}$

Tags: inequality, optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier, symmetric-polynomials

> Let $x,y,z > 0$ such that $3x(x+y+z)=yz$ . Find the minimum value of $$P=\frac{y+z}{x}$$

---

$$3x(x+y+z)=yz\Leftrightarrow 3(x+y)(x+z)=4yz$$

Or $$3(\frac{x}{y}+1)(\frac{x}{z}+1)=4$$

Let $a=x/y, b=x/z ( a,b>0)$

We have: $$4=3(a+1)(b+1)\ge3 \cdot 2 \sqrt  a \cdot 2 \sqrt  b=12 \sqrt {ab} \rightarrow \sqrt {ab}\le \frac 1 3$$

And $$P=\frac{y+z}{x}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\ge \frac{2}{\sqrt {ab}}\ge 6$$

But by WA $Min_P=6+4\sqrt 3$. Is my solution is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $y+z=2u$ and $yz=v^2$, where $v>0$.

Thus, since by AM-GM $$\frac{y+z}{2}\geq\sqrt{yz},$$ we obtain $u\geq v$, 
$$3x^2+6ux-v^2=0$$ or $$x=-u+\sqrt{u^2+\frac{v^2}{3}}$$ and
$$\frac{y+z}{x}=\frac{2u\left(\sqrt{u^2+\frac{v^2}{3}}+u\right)}{\frac{v^2}{3}}\geq\frac{2v\left(\sqrt{v^2+\frac{v^2}{3}}+v\right)}{\frac{v^2}{3}}=6+4\sqrt3.$$ 
The equality occurs for $u=v$ or $y=z$, which says that we got a minimal value.

Comment: Sorry sir. I do not know your solution, have you got another way?

Comment: @DVdivi I added something. Ask your questions.

Comment: Thank sir. This solution is easy to know with me. I really don't know what is "increase respect".

Comment: @DVdivi I added something again. See now.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is wrong because in your solution equality occurs when $a=b=1$ which is not possible because $x=y=z$ doesn't satisfy the constraints. Instead, you should use method of lagrange multipliers. Let $m = \frac{y}{x}$ and $n = \frac{z}{x}$. Then, lagrangian
$$L = m+n-\lambda(3(1+m+n)-mn)$$
(the constraint is obtained by dividing the given equation by $x^2$ on both sides)Equations formed after differentiating $L$ with respect to $m, n$ and $\lambda$ are $$1 =\lambda(3-n)$$
$$1 = \lambda(3-m)$$
$$3(1+m+n)=mn$$
From first two equations, $m=n$, using it in third equation, we get,
$$m^2-6m-3=0$$
$$\implies m = 3+2\sqrt{3}$$
Required minimum value is $6+4\sqrt{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

Use Lagrange multipliers. Call the function you want to minimize $f$ and the constraint $g$. From the condition on the partial derivatives on $y$ and $z$ of $f - \Lambda g$ you can deduce that $y=z$. Finding $x$ with respect to $y$ gives you $x=\frac{\sqrt{12}-3}{3}y$, and this leads to the solution.
 You'd have to check this is actually a minimum (in principle this is only a critical point), but you should be able to verify that by yourself.